# What is the right syntax to use in document.write for tags with attributes?

Tags: javascript, document.write

I am using the following code in JavaScript's *document.write* method:

```html
<script type="text/javascript">
    document.write("<font color="blue">["+time()+"]</font>");
</script>
```

But this doesn't seem to work. How can I fix it?

Comment: The right syntax for `document.write` is not to use it. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/802854/why-is-document-write-considered-a-bad-practice

Comment: Re *"this doesn't seem to work"*: Can you be more specific? What happens?

Comment: OK, the OP has left the building: *"Last seen more than 8 years ago"*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem has nothing to do with HTML directly, but simply with how string literals work in JavaScript (and pretty much every other programming language). If you want to use a `"` character inside a JavaScript string that is delimited with `"` characters then you must escape it: `\"`. Alternatively, use `'` to delimit either the string or the attribute values.

```
document.write("<font color=\"blue\">["+time()+"]</font>");
document.write('<font color="blue">['+time()+"]</font>");
document.write("<font color='blue'>["+time()+"]</font>");
```

---

That said, generating HTML using `document.write` usually isn't a great idea (it only works at load time and is usually better replaced with more reliable server-side code or more reusable [DOM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Document_Object_Model) manipulation)) and the `font` element is deprecated.

Answer (score 2):

Use

```html
<script type="text/javascript">
      document.write("<font color=\"blue\">[" + time() + "]</font>");
</script>
```

or

```html
<script type="text/javascript">
      document.write('<font color="blue">[' + time() + ']</font>');
</script>
```

Note that `time` doesn't exist as a function in JavaScript—I'm assuming you made a function above that wasn't included in your code snippet.

Also, you shouldn't really use `document.write` for anything unless you're just experimenting.

You could test all this out using `console.log` in Firefox's [Firebug](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Firebug_%28software%29) or [Safari](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Safari_%28web_browser%29) / Chrome's *Web Inspector*, and it would be way faster for experimenting than full page refreshes. Also notice how I added spaces on either side of the `+` sign: It is way easier to read.

Answer (score -1):

```
var color = 'blue';     
document.write("<font color="+color+">["+time()+"]</font>");
```

Or

```
 document.write("<font color='blue'>["+time()+"]</font>");
```